# Add single quote to dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic

I am having trouble adding single quote to the last word in the last line of this stored procedure

```
PROCEDURE PROC1(@ProductName nvarchar(40))
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX), @debug    bit = 1

    SET @sql = 'Select [Created] as [Date],[SerialId],[ProductId], CreatedById as [UserId]
                from [Customer].[dbo].[QuotationFlat] QF inner join [Customer].[dbo].[Product] Pt on Pt.Status=QF.' + @ProductName +'
                where '+ @ProductName +' = 1 and Productid = (

    SELECT Productid
    FROM Product
    WHERE Productid = (SELECT MAX(Productid) AS Productid
                       FROM Product 
                       WHERE ProductName = '  + @ProductName + '))'

    SELECT @sql
    -------------Last line Issue------------------
    FROM Product 
    WHERE ProductName = Test))

    ----------But there should be single quote around word TEST
```

Comment: Use `sp_executesql` and parameters.

Comment: Also `quotename()`

Comment: `select quotename('sometext', '''')` But I would use `sp_executesql` and parameterize my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change line

```
FROM Product where ProductName = '  + @ProductName + '))'
```

to

```
FROM Product where ProductName = '''  + @ProductName + '''))'
```